# MongoDB automatically update specific fields when updating document

Tags: mongodb

I have a model which has a field named `update_time`, it stores the timestamp of when the document was updated.

I want it to be automatically updated when I update this document. Currently I have a wrapper function to set the `update_time` and then update the document, but I wonder if MongoDB has inner mechanism to achieve this? Maybe create certain type of indexes? I didn't find document related to such type of index. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using mongodb wrappers such as Mongoose, there is no built in function.